# Link a directory inside Jenkins project workspace

Tags: jenkins, hyperlink, project, customization

I have a directory I create each build named release inside the workspace directory.
When I enter the page of the project, I have the Workspace directory as link and Recent Changes.

Is there a way to also add the Workspace/release directory as link in the page of the project?